# Theme CSS format/html output incorrect

Tags: theme, skin

I am calling a css file from a theme skin folder located at

/skin/frontend/[myfolder]/default/css/reset.css

in a layout block

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head" template="[mylayoutfolder]/html/head.phtml">
    <action method="addCss"><type>css</type><stylesheet>reset.css</stylesheet></action>
</block>
```

This appears in the HTML but incorrectly as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ae2015.uk/skin/frontend/[myfolder]/default/css" reset.css />
```

If I change the < type > to be skin_css  then the output is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ae2015.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/skincss" reset.css />
```

Any clues as to what is going on gang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/reset.css</name><params/><if/></action>
```

Or

```
<action method="addCss"><name>css/reset.css</name><params/</action>
```

The second is basically a shorter version of the first one. Open `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php` if you want some reference.

Comment: DOH! thanks Mayers.  I had it a few lines further down: <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name> <params></params> <if>lt IE 8</if> </action>  ....what a clutz :)

Comment: We all have our moments, glad I helped ;)

Comment: Yer some frantic ctrl-c ctrl-v before going on holiday...come back and find it's all broken :)